# nick attribute of Member object returns none for strange unicode nicknames

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm developing a reminder bot, and I have the ID of the user and a date, time and message for their reminder. There is a command to display the list of reminders. This list should contain the user who created the reminder, which I get from their id. I use the following code to get the `nick` attribute of a member object by id:

```
m = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(user_id)
user_nick = m.nick
```

This works fine if the user has a nickname that uses normal characters, but there is someone on the server with a nickname that uses characters like this:


The member object is fetched successfully (I can get `m.id`) but `m.nick` is `None`. Is there any way to get a user's nickname if they use strange characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and testing, I found [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1256). It turns out `.nick` only returns a nickname if the user has a nickname. The characters in the members username had nothing to do with it. To get the nickname if they have one or the username if they haven't, use `.display_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using the before and after parameters shown in the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update)

here's a code example that might help you lead to the direction you're trying to head towards

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_update(self, before, after):
        if before.nick != after.nick and after.nick is not None: #(if nick is name returns None)
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f":pencil: <@!{before.id}> **nickname edited** \n **Old nickname** \n `{before.nick}` \n \n **New nickname** \n `{after.nick}`",color = 0xfaa31e)
            embed.set_author(name= f"‎{before.name}#{before.discriminator}", icon_url=before.avatar_url)
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=before.avatar_url)
            channel = self.client.get_channel(795726497922809947)
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Let me know if this was helpful and if it wasn't, please explain what you're trying to do exactly because there was little information given to understand what's happening

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not what I'm looking for. I'll edit my question to be more clear. I'm not trying to get the nickname when it changes, I'm trying to get the nickname from the id.